# Fixing sbt OutOfMemoryError on Travis CI

Tags: scala, sbt, out-of-memory, travis-ci, scalac

I have an [sbt project](https://github.com/pathikrit/scalgos) that builds fine locally (because I have the `SBT_OPTS="-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:PermSize=256M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M"` in my `~/.sbtconfig`) but the scala compiler runs out of memory on [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/pathikrit/scalgos). Is there any project specific settings I can add to my project itself that Travis would pick up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fixed it - basically add the same `SBT_OPTS` option to env section of your [.travis.yml](https://github.com/pathikrit/scalgos/blob/master/.travis.yml) file